# What is "Because unicorns" power?

Tags: discussion, unicorns

what is "Because unicorns"? what is the use of this power?

[image: What is "Because unicorns" power]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means that you close a question using the power of unicorns!

[image: unicorn!]

Comment: I was going to post an answer with that image! We are definitely on the same page here.

Comment: Lol :D That's because it's the truth! There's nothing more about it to say.

Comment: That's right. Obviously.

Comment: Someone downvoted this. That's definitly an april fool.

Comment: How to use it? :D I bought it, but don't know how can I use it :D

Comment: Let me see. Will buy it too!

Comment: Then write a short guide for that please :D

Comment: When you have enough reputation to close a question you can then add the option closed because unicorns

Comment: Ah so I cannot do that :D

Comment: no unicorns are mystical