# Is Unicoins a April Fool’s Stunt?

Tags: discussion, unicoins

Is Unicoins a April Fool’s Stunt ?

[image]

Comment: any reason for downvote?

Comment: You have doubts that's why.

Comment: Definitely not.

Comment: Are the unicorns arbitrarily punishing the unbelievers @VisioN, I BELIEVE!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because yes.

Comment: what is wrong with my question how it is different from this http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227363/215358

Comment: Same question here got 30 upvotes http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227641/215358  ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my "sarcastic" answer-

**Yes. It is a Aprils Fools Stunt.**

And it is suppose to be humorous, unfortunately some people took it as genuine and lost a lot of reputation because they asked questions about why they cant access certain privileges ect when they used unicoins to increase their reputation.

Comment: [think she's gained more than she's lost so it's all good](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227566/what-is-because-unicorns-power)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227652/215358

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227651/215358

Comment: April fool http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227654/215358

Comment: Any downvotes as a result of people believing this are just an evening of the distribution of reputation, I say. ;)

Comment: by the way I am not she I am he

Answer (score 22):

They better not be, I've just spent the first 3 hours of my day mining coins, my boss was going to sack me then I explained about how this will improve my efficiency in the long run and now he's helping.

Comment: Improve my efficiency I need to tell my boss that as well.

Answer (score 15):

### No. Unicoins are absolutely real

Answer (score 13):

**Unicoins are as real as this fat unicorn is:**

[image]

Comment: This one is awesome!

Comment: Nice find! Adorable!

Comment: That pink unicorn is not nearly invisible enough.

Answer (score 10):

No, it is not a stunt. [Stack Exchange is serious business](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=1921352#1921352), and they don't support April fool or any other kind of stunts.

P.S. Start Mining.

Answer (score 6):

Nope! Unicoins will be here forever! Just like how unicorns are real.