# Why users are still able to downvote my question? I have "No downvotes, please" Unicoins power

Tags: discussion, support, unicoins

I have purchased "No downvotes, please" Unicoins power using my 75 unicoins

[image]
then I asked a silly question 
[Is Unicoins a April Fool’s Stunt?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227584/215358) (which got almost 8 downvotes) how it is possible for users to downvote my question as this power removed downvote arrow from my question !!

Comment: I would downvote this question but this seems to cruel :)

Comment: @izomorphius: I'm happy to be the _cruel_ one, but I don't have the rep :(

Comment: The answer is very simple, **April Fool** (victim of SE's april fool game ;) ;) just Kidding)

Comment: i would ask for a refund

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have been fooled by Unicorns after buying this power. Only *you* can't see that downvote arrow.

Comment: you mean April fool :)

Comment: ahah, very funny :-D

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your mining efforts are found to be insufficient.

You should mine enough Unicoins to be able to buy this again so that it not only is active for you.

This will totally work! Also, all downvotes will then be deleted within 24 hours!

Comment: Let's see after 24 hours..

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the Unicoins *are* an April Fool's Stunt :)

By the way all the cool stuff you buy with unicoins only affects your profile. Oh, how frustrated I was that my reputation hit the skies only for me. I expected my girlfriend to say something of the sort of "My hero!!!" at least, while she went "Oh well...". So yes, downvote arrows are removed, but only for you. I still see a nice and shiny(and tempting) downvote arrow next to your question. Not much of a help, right ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it makes you immune to downvotes. I think the purpose of the power was to
**remove existing downvotes from existing questions.**

Overall the Unicorn/Unicoin thing is just a April Fools thing.

Comment: And I don't think it actually works.

Comment: How can you claim its not working, heretic?

Comment: I haven't claimed anything. It is simply an opinion. That's why its a comment.