# Are Unicoins an April fools joke?

Tags: discussion, unicoins, april-fools

Just noticed the Unicoins ad on the site and spent some time breaking rocks. Since it popped up 'today' (April 01) I am sure it isn't legit.

BTW, I bought 'no downvotes please' so please don't downvote ;)

Before it goes away! This is what it looked like.

[image]

Comment: How is this a programming question? ;-)

Comment: look at what you can purchse with the coins, and then decide :P

Comment: I think so... Nothing is changing.

Comment: Those with almighty powers should move this to meta then :)

Comment: @Bob Now the question is whether those really work. ;) "Adopt-a-tag" or "no downvotes please", for example.

Comment: Yes, it was quite a surprise.

Comment: i bought "bobblehead" and it works perfectly!

Comment: You deserve upvotes for asking a question about unicorns.

Comment: I was going to upvote, but then you bought no downvotes...

Comment: This is going to be CW in minutes, just watch...

Comment: Damn, I can't even afford 'no downvotes' :(

Comment: @mic_e, break rocks bro! break rocks!

Comment: @Bob, now that's not nice :)

Comment: Ah! I wish I could reopen the post with my Unicoins ;) I'd spend the whole day breaking rocks :)

Comment: I bought the colourful comments... They are FABULOUS!

Comment: FYI the colours for colourful comments are (base) = cyan, _italic_ = magenta, **bold** = red

Comment: I bought the upvoting unicorns. Now I simply can't find enough questions to upvote...

Comment: i bought the bobbleheads, sorry but i can't stop laughing looking at your avatar

Comment: @Dtex, Stack Exchange Inc. does not endorse or encourage behaviors that should not be endorsed or encouraged. However, I encourage laughing at my avatar ;)

Comment: We can use Unicoins to calculate FQ or Foolishness Quotient. Mine is 104 ;)

Comment: Yay for a reopened topic. btw, is it just me, or has it gotten steadily harder to mine unicoins? It seems like most rocks are empty now, where in the beginning I had fairly consistent results.

Comment: Crap - I just put all my money into BitCorns.

Comment: I down-voted and up-voted you just for the unicorn Animation.

Comment: ahahah ! @d.raev me too :)

Comment: I bought the colorful comments. Not sure how long they are going to last.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The moment I visualized millions of intellectual minds breaking stones for unicoins (unicoins?) the realilty dawned upon me that this must be absolutely legit. . . .

Comment: It can't be legit. One of the payment options is bacon, and everyone knows that it is not possible to have spare bacon. No one person can ever have too much bacon. There isn't enough unicoins in the world to get my bacon!

Comment: @John3136 You just made my day!

Comment: I'm here all week. Try the bacon...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating CSS pseudo-elements using jQuery (e.g. :before and :after)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after)

Comment: why All comments are in Comic Sans font and Cyan color...

Comment: @d.raev you only have yourself to blame for that

Answer (score 18):

With "no downvotes please" you also get "one answer that disagrees with you guaranteed".

...

I'm very sorry, but unicoins are not an April Fools joke. This is serious business.

Comment: +1 for a helpful answer

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227634/215358

Answer (score 14):

I believe you didn't read the disclaimer:

> Availability may be limited based on factors. Prohibited where void. Stack Exchange Inc. does not endorse or encourage behaviors that should not be endorsed or encouraged. **Not legal tender except in localities with citizenship rights for unicorns.** Stack Exchange Inc. reserves the right to amend, cancel, or continue this promotion for any reason, including, but not limited to, any reason that would interfere with the invariance, continuation, or non-existence thereof.

Comment: You're right, I didn't. Makes total sense now about this being legit ;)

Comment: @uchamp This is more than legit. Thanks to this answer, I just made a very reasonable amount of reputation money to put towards my legit questions' bounties. I'm going to call this The Unicorn Market Bubble :)))

Answer (score 8):

Yes, just look at the small print:

My favourites:

"endorse or encourage behaviors that should not be endorsed or encouraged"

"Not legal tender except in localities with citizenship rights for unicorns."

Please approve my answer before another fool votes it is not a programming question (on 1st April).

EDIT:
Oh NO, I received a down vote! How's that possible? I spent 80 unicorns for the "No downvote" bonus!

Seriously guys, if you have any sense of humour please vote to reopen the question. I bet it will be closed in minutes by some very serious people!

EDIT2:
REOPEN! REOPEN! REOPEN!

Comment: Everything should be endorsed and/or encouraged!

Answer (score 5):

> Unicorn.
>
> A legendary animal that has been described since antiquity as a beast
>   with a large, pointed, spiraling horn projecting from its forehead.
>   The unicorn was depicted in ancient seals of the Indus Valley
>   Civilization and was mentioned by the ancient Greeks in accounts of
>   natural history by various writers, including Ctesias, Strabo, Pliny
>   the Younger, and Aelian.[1] The Bible also describes an animal, the
>   re'em, which some translations have rendered with the word unicorn.

Unapologetically plagiarized from Wikipedia. You can google it yourself.

Comment: Sense of humor, bro. Sense of humor. It's April 1. ;) Upvote for you anyway because I'm assuming "no downvotes" all around.

Comment: *fistbump* @computerfreaker

Comment: Did you purchase 'No downvotes please'?

Comment: @dmvianna no, I downloaded it illegally. Thanks DCMA!

Comment: not sure how this relates to the question - it's about unico**i**ns

Comment: @Jon duh, unicoins is a subclass of unicorns!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you can "mine" by clicking a virtual rock...**YEAH SEEMS TOTALLY LEGIT!**

If I have an hour to spare, I'd be hacking the mining algorithm by creating something which auto-mines coins, rather than having to sit there clicking...Just do add some level of programming to this, "coin"

Anyone considered...it's "**Fools Gold**" !?

*P.S. Thanks for the down-vote; you clearly have no appreciation for sarcasm!*

Comment: or just use a gaming mouse where one click sends 3 clicks tot the Pc :D

Answer (score 1):

Aww boo hoo, the "people too stiff for you" one I thought I could use on people trying to close my topic. Like it would shake their browser or get rid of their close votes or something. Gosh those people wanting to close my topics annoy me.

All it does is wobble their avatars :( waste of 75 unicoin

Answer (score 1):

Please have in mind most of the styles and effects are visual **JUST TO YOU**.
You can get tons of downvotes (especially if you promote you have the "protection"),
it probably displays 0 **JUST FOR YOU**.

Other reputation boosts are obvioslly just temporary, but **question up/down votes will probably stay**... and will be there in your resume  ;)
Imagine in your profile: "top question with 100 upvotes 
`DO YOU LOVE UNICORNS?`"

Answer (score 0):

Unicoin is legal SO currency. Just bouth that one:

```
Cut everyone's rep

Divide everybody's reputation (except your own) by ten.
```

Sorry, Jon Skeet, you're noob!

Answer (score 0):

May be legit, but rolling it out on 1st of April, doesn't seems to make it legit.