# Downvotes on meta are leading to a question ban

Tags: discussion

It happened to me 3 times so I know very well of what I'm speaking.

One of the strongly downvoted question was simply asking **https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222949/how-is-suspensions-being-administered-to-the-members** => **20 downvotes**.

*Actually this pattern is preventing the freedom of expression*. Of course the question could be improved, but instead of seeing any effort at improving it, the only real result was to disallow unpopoular posts to be written through a q-ban.

I wonder if this is the image this community wants to give of itself.

ps: I've opened this pot believing in the Uniponi, however I believe that it's not something to be proud of to see people behaving as folks with torch, instead of seeing a civil *dialogue*.

I would also draw the attention on the fact that *no one tried to explain the reason why he downvoted.*

*Actually downvotes doesn't show or require any effort, and the huge amount of them proves an emotional behaviour.*

Comment: It isn't quite such a wonderful thing.

Comment: mmm... people can downote the same?

Comment: How do you expect people to show disagreement? Posting comments and answers will not work, as we will end with long unreadable threads.

Comment: I would downvote, but I've only got 3 left after the April Fools Extravaganza and it's still 12 hours until I get a new batch.

Comment: but Unicoinsh shouldn't disallow people to downvote?

Comment: @Revious, do you happen to have a gregorian calendar handy?

Comment: @Oded: in a civil way. Not question banning the person of who you disagree the ideas.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I would upvote, but I'm all out of comment votes. Remind me tomorrow (UTC).

Comment: I think people just downvote because that's the trend on this site and they see others do it. That's really dumb.

Comment: @michaelb958: this example proves the worth of downvote on meta..

Comment: Huh? Downvote != question ban.

Comment: @Miharu, do you mean the 15 downvotes you cast here today (on your first day) are dumb ?

Comment: @Revious I think it rather shows the plus side of downvotes on meta. People disagree with you.

Comment: @Oded: I got question banned 3 times becouse of many dowvotes :-( is this civil?

Comment: @RGraham: and this lead to a q-ban :-) wait and you will see. I will be question banned in a while.

Comment: It shows that you have a propensity to ask questions that are either off-topic or highly unpopular (se sites and meta, respectively). Getting question banned for those reasons is more than OK in my book.

Comment: @Revious I'll take that bet. You won't.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227634/215358

Comment: @Oded: getting banned becouse people doens't share you idea is civil? Can you explain me this concept with some storical example? In which nation disallowing people to express their idea is considered civile?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi- Asking for directions to unicorn land isn't very productive and giving very unreliable and sarcastic answers on questions are not nice and not very good. That's why I made so much downvotes. Especially on answers.

Comment: The thing is - you don't seem to ask yourself **why** your questions are getting downvotes and don't seem to be willing to change your ways to be more productive. You are also mistaking SE for a democracy.

Comment: @Oded: please Oded, make an example of any civil state where there is no expression freedomness..

Comment: @Revious, you may want to read [Question banning should work differently on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109263/164403).

Comment: Please show me where SE is a state/country. Also, China, North Korea are certainly countries where there is no freedom of expression.

Comment: @Oded: democracy is not a synonim of good. **Without making any comparison**, a folk lapidating a woman or many people agreeing that the woman is worst than a male is democracy but it's not civil.

Comment: @Oded: exactly.. Have a look at Amnestry international about what they say on China, North corea and so on.. You choose a nice comparison.

Comment: @Revious - What I find uncivil, is someone going to a site and not following the guidelines and rules the community has set. Even after being told so a few times. And again - a website is not a country.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: on meta I've been question banned 3 times for the downvotes.

Comment: On Meta you have been banned because you were bringing up the same arguments discussed in the past without doing any research and not bringing a **new** perspective on things. And being argumentative and negative to boot. You are confusing cause and effect here.

Comment: @Oded: where I didn't followed the guidelines at opening this question? :-( I quit now, before getting banned. But whithout making any comparison maybe you could want take a while, in your life, reflecting on the reasons why lack of expression freedom is considered a very bad and uncivil stuff by many men better than me and you. Regards.

Comment: @Oded: no, the question banned on meta was only issued automatically for the downvotes. I've evidences of that.

Comment: I think by now you know what downvotes on Meta mean - people disagree that removing downvotes on Meta is a good thing. And if you gave the idea a bit of **thought** (and actually read a bit of the history), and asked a question that reflected both your thinking and the history and brought something new to the discussion, people wouldn't auto downvote.

Comment: The question ban happened due to the downvotes. The downvotes happened  because of your questions - the lack of research and insight into the community and how the sites work.

Comment: @Oded: why did I get the downvotes here? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222949/how-is-suspensions-being-administered-to-the-members

Comment: I don't know why, but at a guess? A suggestion that doesn't show what the benefit to the community would be. It is an opinion that isn't backed up by anything and looks like a reaction to something that happened to the OP rather than something that is trying to consider the long term health of the community. In short, it is bringing up a suggestion and not explaining why it is a good suggestion.

Comment: @Oded: ok, but come on.. all over the world drastic measures are bad considered **extremely bad** and the only reason to use very drastic reason is to **lower the amount of effort** required to obtain from people what they do what you want. here, there would be no need for such drastic measure, and the reputation itself of the word drastic is really near to not civil. ps: easily is a synonim for less effort. Maybe I'm only stupid and I live in a parallel world. Thank you for listening however. I felt in the unicoin joke :-(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible on MSO to question something that people hold dear without getting "disagreement downvoted"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208876/is-it-possible-on-mso-to-question-something-that-people-hold-dear-without-gettin)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get rid of the question ban on Meta; suspend actively harmful users manually](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179093/get-rid-of-the-question-ban-on-meta-suspend-actively-harmful-users-manually)

Comment: Spend more time understanding the community before you post another question

Comment: I liken a question ban on Meta to the crazy people standing on street corners preaching that the end days are coming.  The end effect is the same; you don't listen to them.  You've had your chance for reasonable discourse with the community.  Your own choices led to this happening, so excuse my lack of sympathy for your situation.

Answer (score 4):

> Actually this pattern is preventing the freedom of expression.

You have not defined what you mean by "freedom of expression", but I believe it can be covered adequately according to three general possible meanings.

If you mean "freedom from consequences for asking questions", then consider that such freedom would run counter to one of the core principles of how SE runs: that good questions be voted up and bad questions be voted down is exactly how it should be. Keep in mind that "bad" on Meta also includes feature requests with which people disagree. As much as some of us may not like that feature requests are treated in this way, this is the custom of Meta. I'll note here that the question you linked to in this question has gone through multiple edits, some of which were actually suggesting a method to calculate ban lengths. Undoubtedly some people downvoted on this basis, even if they did not object to other parts of the question.

If what you mean by "freedom of expression" the legal notion of free speech, then the response here is that I do not know of any law that compels a private entity like Stack Exchange to provide a platform for people to express themselves.

If what you mean by "freedom of expression" is the idea that it is healthy for SE sites to allow users to express their opinions about the governance of the sites, then SE is doing an excellent job. Consider that it is possible for any user to come on Meta and post a question or post an answer.

Now, *one* of the reasons there are bans in place is that people who repeatedly ask bad questions are a drain on the system. Resource are limited, and people who take the time reading and dealing with bad questions could be spending their time doing something for the site. Which leads me to this:

> Actually downvotes doesn't show or require any effort, and the huge amount of them proves an emotional behaviour.

I've seen very little evidence of *emotional* behavior in voting. I've gotten some downvotes that I believe (but cannot prove) were due to someone being pissed at having their question closed, but they were rare. And regarding effort, as I've mentioned above resources are limited. Most likely, when someone downvotes a post and does not put some effort towards improving *this* post, the choice is not between improving *this* post and doing *nothing*, but between improving *this* post and doing something else useful for the SE sites. The time spent improving a bad post can be spent answering a question, or editing a post which has some flaws but is closer to perfection, or any number of other tasks. In other words, the effort is not *lacking*; it is just spent *elsewhere*.

The way to avoid a negative outcome here is the same as anywhere on the internet, before posting, the user should spend time lurking and learning the customs of the site. This is important anywhere but even more so on SE sites because posts are voted on and such votes carry potentially substantial consequences, and even more on Meta due to its peculiarities.

And let me add this, because I've not been active on Meta that long so this is still fresh for me: I've seen some suggestions being heavily downvoted on Meta that were suggestions that crossed my mind early on. **I could have been the one asking these questions and getting slammed.** But instead of asking right away, I lurked and realized how Meta is different, and then I spent a good deal of time looking at old questions.