# Where did unicoins and unicorn powers has gone?

Tags: discussion, fun, unicoins, april-fools

yesterday when I visited http://stackoverflow.com and http://meta.stackoverflow.com there was a banner of unicoins in right sidebar

[image]

after mining and collecting unicoins I purchased “No downvotes, please” Unicoins power and also got some downvotes on this question [Is Unicoins a April Fool’s Stunt?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227584/215358)  and upvotes on this question [Why users are still able to downvote my question? I have "No downvotes, please" Unicoins power](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227634/215358) now where all my powers and unicoin has gone? was it a [April Full Joke](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227584/215358) ?

Comment: yes it was a joke

Comment: @MohammadFaisal Who told you that? :( They lied.

Comment: as a unicorn a mythical character so are the unicoins. just wake up and go to work

Comment: unicoins are like you putting pic of Katrina Kaif

Comment: ha ha ha ha ...

Comment: @TravisJ how it is possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227584/215358 ?

Comment: @SubodhGhulaxe it's a duplicate because you got your answer already in that question.  It was an April Fool's "stunt", and it is no longer April 1st, so the unicoins and everything associated with them is over and done with until next year's april Fool's stunt..

Answer (score 8):

The unicoins are not a joke- they were actually mailed to Stack Exchange on New Year's from the unicorns in big cardboard boxes. It took a long time for them to get to SE Headquarters because the mail is slow from Unicorntopia.

In fact, I got a peek at the online shipping tracker:

[image]

The coincidence that the Unicoins just happened to arrive on April Fools, is, well, just that. A coincidence.